# javascript cookie from user input

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am working on javascript cookies. The material provided to me was very short and no examples. I am trying to create a html form that will allow user to input name and favorite pet when page is refreshed it will display the username and favorite pet in the html page as well for allowing user to change pet. I do not understand how to assign a users input to a cookie and then display it on html. This is what I have so far

```
<html>

<head>

<script>

var x = document.getElementById("nm").value;
var y = document.getElementById("fp").value;
document.cookie = x;


function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
var name = cname + "=";
var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
var user=getCookie("username");
if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + user);
} else {
   user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
   if (user != "" && user != null) {
       setCookie("username", user, 30);
   }
   }
}

</script>

</head>

<body onload="checkCookie()">

    <header>
        Cookies
    </header>
    <br>

<form name="myForm"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="nm"><br>
<br>
Favorite Pet: <input type="text" name="fpet" id=""fp"><br>
<br>
<button onclick="">Show cookies</button>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to set html to a specific value, use `innerHTML`.

There are several other things about your code that can be improved, however I hope to have given you a quick help here.

```
<html>

<head>

<script>




function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
var name = cname + "=";
var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
console.log(ca)
for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
var user=getCookie("username");
if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + user);
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = user;
} else {
   user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
   if (user != "" && user != null) {
       setCookie("username", user, 30);
   }
   }
}

</script>

</head>

<body onload="checkCookie()">

    <header>
        Cookies
    </header>
    <br>

<form name="myForm"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

<hr>

<p>Previously entered name:</p>
<b><p id="name"></p></b> 

<hr>

Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="nm"><br>
<br>
Favorite Pet: <input type="text" name="fpet" id="fp"><br>
<br>
<button onclick="">Show cookies</button>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var x = document.getElementById("nm").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("fp").value;
  document.cookie = x;
</script>
</body>

</html>
```